# Does each Java class in an app need to have a different unique serial version ID?

Tags: java, class, serialization, version

From I read online, it seems a good practice to create a serial version ID for a class.

My question is that in an application, do I have to create an unique ID for each class?

Or can I simply assign the following ID to each class in my application?

`private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You only need a serial version ID for classes that will be serialized, i.e. mostly those that implement `Serializable`
- The ID is per class, it's not a problem if two classes have the same
- It's only necessary if there is a chance that serialized instances will be deserialized by a different version of the program. This is often not the case.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't matter what the ID is for the specific class - it's the serialization format version *for that class*. The class name itself is still serialized, so it's not like it has to be unique across *all* classes. (Of course, you *may* find other ways in which having a different version number for each class would be useful. I can't think of any off hand, but that's a different matter.)

Using a constant value is fine - but you *do* need to make sure you change it when you've genuinely changed the serialization format (e.g. by adding a field).

Mind you, I'd prefer to use something like [Protocol Buffers](http://protobuf.googlecode.com) which is rather more graceful with backward/forward compatibility :)